# Log4Net: RollingFile Appender - Appending .TXT

Tags: log4net

I have the following working config:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\\App_Data\\log.txt" />
```

I want to have the log file appear like this

```
log.2012-11-28.txt
log.2012-11-29.txt
```

And so on. Notice the .txt at the end.

How do I change the **file value** in the config to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to appender configuration, please make sure that you don't have other rollingStyle added

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datePattern value="'log.'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
```